# Rendering multiple pages with Twig

Tags: php, twig

I am building a website using Twig as my template engine (without Symfony or any other frameworks). How do I go about rendering several different PHP pages?

So far I only have one page – *index.php* – which in my project is supposed to handle the homepage. If I want to add more (for instance *about.php*, *article.php*, etc.), what would be the best approach to do that? Do I need to create those other pages and use the same code as below, changing only the template file name, or is there some other way to handle the routing?

This is my *index.php*:

````
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader(__DIR__ . '/templates');
$twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);
echo $twig->render('index.html.twig', ['title' => 'Project Title']);
?>```
````

Comment: Why do you think Twig on its own can handle the fundamentals like code structure and routing? Why not use a framework?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I am still new to both Twig and its underlying concepts, so I am trying learn the fundamentals without delving into complex frameworks and their structure at the moment.

Comment: Not all frameworks are complex, for example, fat-free https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/getting-started which you could just use the routing and still use twig. Else pages like `article` will quickly become unmanageable.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you for the recommendation, I will take a look.

Comment: @AndrewHayes Lawrence is right, twig isnt meant to handle more complex actions like page routing. It just the template engine. While you could set something up very simply for routing I find it best to leverage the work of others. If you need a router I would recommend the [Symfony Router Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing.html)